# ошибка в SQLite

Tags: c, база-данных, sqlite

Пробую создать таблицу но получаю ошибку `SQL table create error: near "(": syntax error`.Все проверил, вроде верно.

```
sql = sqlite3_mprintf(
         "CREATE TABLE ('%q')(" \
         "('%q')    INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL," \
         "('%q')    TEXT    NOT NULL," \
         "('%q')    INT     NOT NULL," \
         "('%q')    CHAR(50)," \
         "('%q')    INT  NOT NULL);"
        , tableName
        , SCHEME_ID
        , SCHEME_NAME
        , SCHEME_AGE
        , SCHEME_COUNTRY
        , SCHEME_POPULATION);

rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-моему, у вас просто перебор со скобками... Попробуйте

```
CREATE TABLE '%q'
('%q' INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
 '%q' TEXT NOT NULL,
 '%q' INT NOT NULL, 
 '%q' CHAR (50), 
 '%q'  INT  NOT NULL);
```

Comment: Как оказалось вы правы, спасибо